# Cancellation of a long running task in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

I am working on a project where we have lots of separate components are running and my agenda is to cancel the component process in between based on user input.

For example: I have 6 windows service that do all the work and 1 another windows service that is responsible for distribution of work. so once the work is send to worker windows service there is no control over it. this worker windows service do some time consuming task, calling several function, interect with database etc. I want to cancel the task in between of working.

The traditional approch we use for cancelation will no longer work here as...
1. I am not iterating any loop where I can continuosly check for Cancel flag.
2. Since the component is totally separate and once they start working, new instance is created of that component and not able to pass any value to that component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried implementing and firing custom events based on specific time iteration and handling them when they needed to be handled? ([Take a look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)) Also it would be helpful to know if you're multithreading or running everything on a single thread.

Comment: You can stop windows service this way: http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/, but you still need to check something in your working thread(not cross process, maybe cross thread).